# Foldable instance for a Trie-Set

Tags: haskell, trie, foldable

I have a Set-like data structure, implemented as a Trie, with a definition like this:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Foldable (Foldable, foldr)
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data Trie a = Trie { endHere :: Bool 
                   , getTrie :: M.Map a (Trie a)
                   } deriving (Eq)
```

And an insert operation that looks like this:

```
insert :: (Ord a, Foldable f) => f a -> Trie a -> Trie a
insert = foldr f (\(Trie _ m) -> Trie True m) where
  f e a = overMap (M.alter (Just . a . fromMaybe (Trie False M.empty)) e)

overMap :: Ord b => (M.Map a (Trie a) -> M.Map b (Trie b)) -> Trie a -> Trie b
overMap f (Trie e m) = Trie e (f m)
```

And I can get a *kind* of `foldr` that looks like this:

```
foldrTrie :: ([a] -> b -> b) -> b -> Trie a -> b
foldrTrie f i (Trie a m) = M.foldrWithKey ff s m where
  s    = if a then f [] i else i
  ff k = flip (foldrTrie $ f . (k :))
```

But I can't figure out the `Foldable` instance for `Trie`. The `foldrTrie` seems to have all of the necessary functionality, but I just can't figure out the types.

Here's an example of the `foldr` behaviour I'm looking for:

```
fromList :: (Ord a, Foldable f, Foldable g) => f (g a) -> Trie a
fromList = foldr insert (Trie False M.empty)

toList :: (Ord a) => Trie a -> [[a]]
toList = foldr (:) [] -- replace foldr here with foldrTrie and you'll get the 
                      -- desired behaviour

toList (fromList ["abc", "def"]) -- ["abc","def"]
```

What I can't manage is the type signature for `Foldable`:

```
instance Foldable Trie a where
```

I tried making my `Trie` have a second type parameter:

```
data Trie a (f a) = Trie { endHere :: Bool
                         , getTrie :: M.Map a (Trie a (f a))
                         } deriving (Eq)
```

So that I might be able to do something like this:

```
instance Foldable Trie a f where
  foldr f i (Trie a m) = M.foldrWithKey ff s m where
    s    = if a then f [] i else i
    ff k = flip (foldrTrie $ f . (k :))
```

but I couldn't figure out the types.

A more general way to frame the question might be like this: if I had a data structure which could store *only* lists, would I be able to define `foldr` on that data structure, so it treated the lists it stored as each element? What would the type for that data structure look like?

Comment: `instance Foldable Trie where foldr f = foldrTrie $ flip $ foldr f`. I see no reason why a "Trie can only store Foldable things".

Comment: This Trie is intended as a Data structure to store sequences (or, more generally, `Foldable`s), of `Ord` elements. The things stored in the `Trie` *have* to be `Foldable`, because that's the only way to insert something into the `Trie`. I'd like to be able to access the things in the `Trie` again, using `foldr`, preserving their sequence-like structure.

Comment: I'm sure there are many ways to represent a sequence, but I fail to see how `Foldable` does so. Using only the `Foldable` interface to `Trie`, I see no way to write your desired function, because a `Foldable` simply doesn't do that. `foldrTrie` is more general than `foldr : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Trie a -> b`.

Comment: I suppose what I'm asking is, if I had a data structure that could store *only* (say) lists, could I implement `Foldable` on that data structure? I can manage the mechanics (I think); but it's the types that are holding me up. What would the type signature for that structure look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably **not** what you want to do, but you could wrap a generic data structure into a GADT that only allows lists to be stored on the leafs. Simple example using trees instead of Tries for simplicity's sake: suppose the generic data structure is `Tree`, and we want to make `LTree` which only allows trees of lists:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Tree

foldrForListTrees :: ([a] -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree [a] -> b
foldrForListTrees = error "This is the one you are supposed to be able to write"

data LTree a where
    MkLTree :: Tree [a] -> LTree [a]

instance Foldable LTree where
    foldr f ys0 (MkLTree xs) = foldrForListTrees f ys0 xs
```

Comment: In this case, it would also be possible to define `Trie` as such a GADT directly, at the cost of adding `[]` around its type parameter everywhere.

Comment: I think this might actually be a really good option. I had intended to generalise the Trie a little bit more anyway (i.e, having it as a mapping structure, by replacing `endHere` with types other than just `Bool`) so possibly I could have an `STrie` GADT (with the `[]` around its type parameter everywhere), and then another `Trie` which could implement `Foldable` in a different way. Thanks!